# Jquery focus() doesn't work when tabbing?

Tags: jquery, focus

I have setup some basic code that triggers on focus of various input fields:

```
        var div = '<div class="formHint">Content</div>';                 

       $j('.textbox').blur(function() {
          $j(".formHint").remove();
        });


       $j('.textbox').click(function() {

        $j(this).focus().before(div);
        $j(this).prev(".formHint").animate({ 
     marginLeft: "325px",
     opacity: "1"
     }, 200 );


});
```

Basically, it inserts a DIV after .textbox on focus(), and remove all .textbox on blur().

The problem is, when you tab through the elements, they don't gain focus. Jquerys documentation says

> In recent browser versions, the event
>   can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the
>   element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard
>   commands, such as the Tab key, or by
>   mouse clicks on the element.

But after doing some research, I don't understand how to apply this?

Comment: I think your understanding of the documentation is a little off, it's for *other* elements, say even a plain `<div>`, you can let it have focus by giving it a `tabindex` property, for example: `<div tabindex=5">`, now you can tab to/focus that element.

Comment: oh ok I see... but still, how do I get the functionality I am looking for (focus on tab)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the focus event, not the click event:

```
$('.textbox').focus(function() {
    $(this).before(div);
    $(this).prev(".formHint").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "325px",
        opacity: "1"
    }, 200 );
});
```

Comment: I was just realizing that! Now I feel like a moron... need to a slow down a bit. Thanks!